# Qual è la differenza tra "la mucca" e "la vacca"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, difference, synonym

Voglio sapere la differenza tra **la mucca** e **la vacca**. Sono uno studente straniero a Torino. Ho sempre pensato che vacca significasse "cow" in inglese. Tuttavia oggi ho visto che mucca significa anche "cow". Qual è la differenza tra loro? Sono la stessa cosa? O è solo una differenza dialettale o regionale? Ad esempio, so che a Torino di solito diciamo "anguria" anziché "cocomero". È qualcosa del genere?

Grazie!

Comment: Sostanzialmente sono sinonimi. A volte "vacca" non si usa perché ha un doppio senso, ma un allevatore non direbbe mai ho 20 mucche.

Comment: Capisco. Quindi, di solito gli allevatori dicono "vacca". Ma qual è il secondo senso di "vacca" che lo rende inappropriato?

Comment: "Donna di facili costumi"

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! A quanto pare, la tua domanda è un duplicato di [quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1711/707).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prendendo le definizioni del vocabolario Treccani:

[Vacca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vacca/)

> **vacca** s. f. [lat. vacca]. – 1. La femmina adulta dei bovini:

[Mucca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mucca/)

> **mucca** s. f. [dallo svizz.-ted. *Mugg* (in origine, la parola indicava le vacche svizzere, comperate alla fiera di Lugano)]. – Vacca lattifera. È voce tosc. largamente diffusa in tutta Italia perché non ha il tono spreg. che alla voce *vacca* deriva dagli usi figurati

Quindi il termine diciamo "tecnico" sarebbe *"vacca"* e per questo viene utilizzato dagli allevatori, mentre *"mucca"* è un termine più specializzato (vacca da latte) originariamente toscano, ma diffusosi in tutta Italia; come fatto giustamente notare da @CarLaTeX nel suo commento, la maggior parte delle persone li usa come sinonimi intercambiabili.

Da notare che esistono delle espressioni "fisse", ad es si dice sempre *"mercato delle vacche"* (mai *"delle mucche"*) così come si parla di *"morbo della mucca pazza"* (e non *"della vacca pazza"*)

Per quanto riguarda l'uso inappropriato perché spregiativo (sempre dalla stessa definizione di **vacca** del vocabolario Treccani):

> Con sign. fortemente spreg., donna di facili costumi, che si prostituisce o si concede con grande facilità; per lo più come ingiuria volgare, anche in funzione di agg., di frasi offensive, bestemmie e imprecazioni: *sei una v.!*; *è una gran v., quella ragazza, o quella fa la v. con tutti; porca vacca!* Valore spreg. ha anche in altri casi, riferiti per es. a donna sformata, o trasandata, oppure in similitudini: *stava sdraiato (o più spesso sdraiata) come una vacca* (cfr. anche *stravaccato*).

Comment: Onestamente, non sapevo nulla del dizionario Treccani. Ora trovo che sia un'ottima fonte! Grazie per l'informazione. Da ora in poi userò sicuramente il Treccani.

Comment: @tamuno:  Magari ti interesserebbe dare un'occhiata a questo: [What good reference works on Italian are available online?](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/122/707).

Comment: Grande! Alcuni di questi websites sono tesori! Apprezzato molto!